# After taking Picture, how to select Ok or Cancel button? using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, android-camera, appium

path of done button on camera screen:

[image: path of done button on camera screen]

I have used this code to locate done button

```
driver1.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[contains(@text,'done_buttonS')]").click();
```

camera screen with locater:

[image: camera screen with locater]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the element in locator and then click on it:

`driver1.findElementById('com.android.camera2:id/done_button').click();`

Comment: Thanks Thejus Krishna your suggestion is working. do you Know the reason why appium unable to locate using xpath?

Comment: There is no text - done_button in the element that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
int eventNumber = 66; 
Runtime.getRuntime()
   .exec("cmd /C adb shell input keyevent " + eventNumber);
```